# Getting 401 from fetch in React - Passing sessionId

Tags: reactjs, fetch, session-cookies

I'm building react app, first screen is a login form that is calling a GET rest api resource in other host (8080)(CORS extension on chrome was installed to overcome CORS issue).

After logging in successfully, trying to perform another GET fetch but this time am getting 401!

Tried setting the credentials: 'same-origin' or credentials: 'include' (in both calls, login and second one) but it didn't help!

```
fetch('http://<some host>:8080/WebServices/api/SessionManager/login?userName='
        + this.state.userName + '&password=' + this.state.password,
        {
            //credentials: "include",
            //mode: "no-cors"
        })
        .then(
            (response) => {
                if (response.status < 200 || response.status > 300) {
                    console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                        response.status);
                    this.state.showError = true;
                    this.state.errorMessage = 'Please enter a valid credentials.';

                    return;
                } else {
                    localStorage.setItem('session', response);
                    console.log("Response ======>", response);
                    window.location.href = '/main';

                }

            }
        )
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

second call:

```
function getSession(){
   return localStorage.getItem('session').then(response => JSON.parse(response))
}

function getProjectDetails(){
   let params = getSession();

   let headers = new Headers();
   fetch('http://<host>:8080/WebServices/api/ProjectManager/getProjectDetails?userSessionId=', params
  // {
  //   //credentials: "include",
  //   //credentials: "same-origin",
  //   //crossdomain: true,
  //   //mode: 'no-cors',
  //   //headers: headers
  // }
  )
  //.then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({ projectsDetails: data })
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(console.log);
```

}
   class App extends Component {

Is there a way to get the session from browser cookies and set it into the header or parameters of fetch? how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right you are asking how to store and retrieve stored values from the cookies.

First you need to store the data you get from the first fetch with, be aware that must convert he json response to string with JSON.stringify.

```
localStorage.setItem('session', JSON.stringify(response));
```

An then you can retrieve it with:

```
localStorage.getItem('session');
```

LocalStorage has to be stored as json, and decode it after getItem().

So in order to add the session params to the second fetch you can do as follows:

```
function getSession(){
 return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'))
}
// second fetch,
function secondFetch(){
 var params = getSession();
 // in var params you have the data stored so now you can do the second fetch
}
```

I hope I've been of help to you, anything don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response. I did the set from first call but when trying to do the get from getSession getting: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'then' of null.

and generall talking, the params should be provided like this to fetch: fetch('url', params,...

Please be aware that after login is succeeding I'm routing to /main, maybe this cause the lost of data?!

And the main question if It's the right approach! maybe to stick to credentials: 'same-origin' or credentials:'include' approach... I don't know :~

Comment: @zbeedatm In the first fetch, inside the then() where you redirect to /main you need to store the response (If this response is the one you will use after), so inside this you use the localStorage.setItem('session', response).

Comment: @zbeedatm Sorry, i've got confused with react-native async storage, localStorage it is not a PROMISE so you don't need to use the then(), the response it is not asynchronous, i've updated my code also.

Comment: OK. updated but still getting 401 !!! Tried to print the param and I noticed that it's null.

Comment: @zbeedatm in the first fetch, first then, inside de if where you redirect to /main, there, do a console.log(response), if that is right, then do a localStorage.setItem('session', response). Now you stored your response (I guess with the user credentials) that you can recover anywhere in your app with getItem('session').

Comment: Yes my bad, the set was in wrong place. Now I'm getting a weird error that I'm investigating (didn't get it before): Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.

Comment: @zbeedatm be aware than in the second fetch, at least here in stackoverflow you are still using then() and async / await. Check my response for the updated code without the promises syntax.

Comment: If I disable the call to second fetch this error does not happen... what can be?

Comment: @zbeedatm are you doing:                                                                          
function getSession(){
 return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('session'))
}
// second fetch,
function getProjectDetails(){
 var params = getSession(); console.log(params)
 // your second fetch
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195615/discussion-between-josep-vidal-and-zbeedatm).

Comment: I changed the title and accepted your answer regarding how to pass the response. But the main problem of 401 still exists cause the response coming from login fetch call is empty and have no cookies I guess.